# Android Multi Screen Incompatibility

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have a background image. There is a gold image on this background. I want to add an edittext right next my gold image and I want edittext size to be equel for every screen resulations.I tried weight and linear layout both horizontal and vertical. Afterwards I screened the result on every screen resolutions but it did not work. The content of the edit dext comes differently on every screen resolutions. I have been striving to resolve this issue for hours but I douln't of reached any way out yet. Please help me.

```
<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayoutxmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@drawable/mainpagebackgrounduye"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.englishapps.com.checkyourenglishvocabulary.MainActivity"
android:weightSum="1"
android:id="@+id/anasayfa"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:measureWithLargestChild="false">


<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="0.10"
>

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight=".8"></LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="0.2"
android:id="@+id/gll">

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight=".15"
android:padding="0dp"
android:id="@+id/sst"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"></LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="0dp"
android:layout_weight="0.93"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp">

<EditText
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:id="@+id/goldtxt"
android:enabled="false"
android:editable="false"
android:allowUndo="false"
android:autoText="false"
android:text="0"
android:textColor="#010101"
android:layout_weight=".3"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"
android:padding="0dp"
android:textIsSelectable="false"/>

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="0.15"
android:padding="0dp"
android:paddingLeft="0dp"
android:paddingTop="0dp"
android:paddingRight="0dp"
android:paddingBottom="0dp"></LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="0.16"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:id="@+id/ustlinear"></LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="0.54"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:id="@+id/orta">

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="0.3"
android:id="@+id/tasklinear"></LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="0.7"
android:id="@+id/ortalinear"></LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="0.2"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:id="@+id/alt">

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:id="@+id/altlinear"
android:layout_weight=".7"></LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:id="@+id/reklamlinear"
android:layout_weight=".3"></LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: I want to like this]

[image: layout-wxga 10.1inch]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add this at code

```
 DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();                       
 getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
```

create different xml for layout
screen for 320dp-hdpi, 480dp-xhdpi, 600dp-xxhdpi, 720dp-xxxhdpi

Comment: but its hard way, because have many screens and many page. I handle it for buttons, i add buttons dynamicaly and i use weitht for all screens.
I need only calculate text size for all resulation and same place(right the gold image)

Comment: its detect different screen size.if u create this size almost its work in all devise.and u r add dynamic button u can set weight according screen eg.(metrics.widthPixels >= 1600 || metrics.heightPixels >= 2560).u hve to check for all screen